# Uniform convergence of power sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

I'd like to prove that the power sequence

$f_n(x) = x^n$

doesn't **converges uniformly** on $[0,1]$, but it does on $[0,a]$ if $a < 1$.

My textbook states that a sequence of functions converges uniformly to $f(x)$ if

$ \forall \, \epsilon > 0 \,\, \exists \, \overline{n}_{\epsilon}: \forall x \in A \quad |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

So I found that $f_n(x)$ converges **pointwise** to 
$f(a,b) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{$0 \leq x < 1 \implies 0$}\\
       \text{$x = 1 \,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\implies 1$}
     \end{cases}
$

So I tried to apply the definition of **uniform convergence**, but I can't understand how could I find an $\epsilon > 0: \forall \, \overline{n}, \,\,\exists \, x \in [0,1], \,\,\, \exists \, n \geq \overline{n}: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$

Did I misunderstand something about the definition? Thank you in advance

Comment: How can I construct that sequence?

Comment: $f_n(1-1/2) = (1/2)^n$, $\,\, f(1-1/2) = 0$. But $(1/2)^2 < 1/2$

Comment: I take $x_n=1-1/n$, not $1-1/2$. You have $f_n(1-1/n)=(1-1/n)^n\to 1/e$ and $f_n(1-1/n)\geq \frac{1}{4}$ for all $n$ (so take $\varepsilon =1/4$ instead of $1/2$).

Comment: Okay, so $x_n \to 1/e$ does the trick. Is it ok to take a value of $x$ for $f_n(x)$ that depends on $n$?

Comment: I don't understand your question :  Is it ok to take a value of x for fn(x) that depends on n? Also, it's not correct that $x_n\to 1/e$.

Comment: I mean, we know that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ (pointwise), and to find that limit function I took a fixed x and checked the limit of the sequence $x^n$. But $lim_{n \to \infty} (1-1/n)^n = 1/e \neq 0$, although $0 < (1-1/n) < 1 \,\, \forall \, n$. So the limit should be $0$, according to the limit function that I definied in my question

Comment: What you've written is not a pointwise limit. Pointwise limit is fixing $x$ and looking at the limit $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}f_n(x)$. You're putting different points in different functions. There is no specific $y<0$ for which $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}f_n(y)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the way that I think is more constructive to think about it, uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $A$ is equivalent to $\underset{x\in A}{\sup} \vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert \overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}  0$.
So if for all $n$ there exists $x_n\in A$ such that:

$\vert f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\vert\equiv c>0$

then you would show that there is no uniform to $f$. You have to consider just one $f$, since uniform convergence also implies point-wise convergence.

You could have also gone another route. If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to $f$,  then $f$ is a continuous function, which you can see that $f$ is not.

Comment: Could you please explain which $x_n$ should I consider?

Comment: For example if you want to show for $c=\frac{3}{4}$, you would want that $x_n^n-0=\frac{3}{4}$. So for example $x_n:=\Big( \frac{3}{4} \Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} $ would work.

Comment: But I know that $f_n(x) = x^n$ converges on $[0,a]$ if $a < 1$. Your proof proves also that my sequence doesn't converge uniformly on that set

Comment: It won't since for any $1>a>0$, $x_n$ would eventually be larger than $a$, and thus not be relevant to the interval $[0,a]$. Furthermore for all $c>0$, choosing $x_n =\sqrt[n]{c}$ would mean that $x_n>a$ eventually.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense. Thank you very much. Could you please check my last comment below my question, and tell me what you think? For instance, $lim_{n \to \infty} (3/4)^{1/n} = 1$, but this conflicts with the pointwise limit that I definied in my question